# Want to apply different classes to each selected menu elements

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i am having an issues with the customizing of wordpress menu theme. I want to apply different classes on each of the selected menu.

This is exactly what i want.

```
<ul>
<li class="item1">Home Page</li>
<li class="item2">About Page</li>
<li class="item3">Contact Page</li>
</ul>
```

When the menu item is clicked different classes would be applied on each of the selected menu item
For example i want to click menu item1 a class active1 should be added to the selected

element simillary if i clicked item2 a class active2 should be added to the selected

element

This is how i am trying to achieve this but its not working

```
    add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
    function special_nav_class($classes, $item){

     if ($item == 'Home Page') {        
if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
                    $classes[] = 'active1';
                }
    }

if ($item == 'Home Page') {         
if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
                    $classes[] = 'active2';
                }
    }
         return $classes;

    }
```

Can Anyone please help me? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried to add custom classes under Appearance admin panel? 
If not, go to Admin > Appearance > Menus. On the top right corner click "show options" and check CSS classes. Then, you add individual classes within the menu items of your selected menu. 

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why its not working? PHP errorlog?

Answer (score 0):

This requires some jQuery

#### PHP

First, let's construct the menu:

```
$menu = array(
    '1' => 'Home',
    '2' => 'About',
    '3' => 'contact',
);
```

#### PHP/HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
<?php foreach ($menu as $id => $item): ?>
    <li><a class="item item-<?= $id; ?>" href="#"><?= $item; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.item', function () {
            $('.item').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

***After reading more closely I see you want to add the class in PHP. In order for me to answer your question, I need to know how the `$classes` array looks.***